# HTML component when placed in react doesn't follow styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I am currently using an HTML template and am trying to return those as react components, however when I run the HTML code natively the page looks like this.

[image]

However, running the same code being returned by a react component, it is almost as if the components are only taking up half the page. Some of the elements such as the text of the name and collar have been changed but I haven't touched any of the DOM elements so I don't know why the proportions are not correctly outputted. Any advice on how I can combat this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

1. Check your css.
   You have some styling overrides on your react side. Those styles are overriding the ones defined on the html template that you are trying to render. Look for any styling your react app is doing on list items.
2. Its not exactly a good idea, returning a whole html template from the react component. Since we don't know your use-case, can't give any advice on this.
3. Try a react component library, if you want to create a similar page using pure react components. Will be a more sensible approach.